# Regex starting with a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to filter the following string with the regular expressions:

```
TEST^AB^^HOUSE-1234~STR2255
```

I wanna get only the string `"HOUSE-1234"` and I've to test the string always with the beginning `"TEST^AB^^"` and ending with the `"~"`.

Can you please help me how the regex should look like?

Comment: You want to extract the string between "TEST^AB^^" and "~" ??

Comment: You need to define you problem much more explicitly. Probably half of regex problems are because people haven't thought enough about *exactly* what the pattern should be.

Comment: @Matt, also half of regex problems could be resolved without regex!

Comment: @RaffaelVögeli: So it always begins with `TEST^AB^^` or does it always begin with *sometext* followed by `^^`. This is why defining the problem **exactly** is important.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: True enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "TEST^AB^^HOUSE-1234~STR2255";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"TEST\^AB\^\^(.+?)~").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\^\^(.*?)\~` pattern which matches start with `^^` and ends with `~`

```
string s = @"TEST^AB^^HOUSE-1234~STR2255";
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"\^\^(.*?)\~", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Output will be;

```
HOUSE-1234
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/SSkQrr).

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern=@"\^\^(.*)\~";
Regex re=new Regex(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this without regex:

```
    var str = "TEST^AB^^HOUSE-1234~STR2255";
    var result = (str.StartsWith("TEST^AB^^") && str.IndexOf('~') > -1) 
                ? new string(str.Skip(9).TakeWhile(c=>c!='~').ToArray())
                : null;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the little information you've given us (and assuming that the `TEST^AB` isn't necessarily constant), this might work:

```
(?:\^\^).*(?:~)
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/XVGRrZr0xo)

Or if `TEST^AB` is constant, you can throw it in too

```
(?:TEST\^AB\^\^).*(?:~)
```

The important part is to remember that you need to escape the `^`

Answer (score 0):

Don't even need the RegEx for something that well defined. If you want to simplify:

```
string[] splitString;
if (yourstring.StartsWith("TEST^AB^^"))
{
    yourstring = yourstring.Remove(0, 9);
    splitString = yourstring.Split('~');
    return splitString[0];
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

(TEST\^AB\^\^)((\w)+-(\w+))(\~.+)

There are three groups :

```
(TEST\^AB\^\^) : match yours TEST^AB^^
((\w)+\-(\w+)) : match yours HOUSE-123
(\~.+) : match the rest
```